# update threaded tkinter gui

Tags: python, multithreading, user-interface, tkinter, gpio

I have a small display connected to my pi.
Now I have a Python script that measures the time between two events of the gpio headers.
I want to display this time (the script to get this time is working perfectly). For that I created a `tkinter` window.
There, I have a label that should display this time.
I have threaded the gui function to make it possible for the program to still listen to the GPIO pin.

```
def guiFunc():
    gui = Tk()
    gui.title("Test")
    gui.geometry("500x200")
    app = Frame(gui)
    app.grid()
    beattime = Label(app, text = "test")
    beattime.grid()
    gui.mainloop()


gui_thread = threading.Thread(target = guiFunc)
gui_thread.start()


while True:
    time.sleep(.01)
    if (GPIO.input(3)):
        time = trigger()  #trigger is the function to trigger the 'stopwatch'
        global beattime
        beattime['text'] = str(time)
        while GPIO.input(3): #'wait' for btn to release (is there a better way?)
            print "btn_pressed"
```

So the program isn't doing anything since I added these lines:

```
global beattime
beattime['text'] = str(time)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `tkinter.StringVar`

```
# omitting lines
global timevar
timevar = StringVar()
timevar.set("Test")
beattime = Label(app, textvariable=timevar)
# omitting lines

#changing the text:
while True:
    time.sleep(.01)
    if (GPIO.input(3)):
       time = trigger()  #trigger is the    function to trigger the 'stopwatch'
       timevar.set(str(time))
       root.update() #just in case

       while GPIO.input(3): #'wait' for btn to release (is there a better way?)
          print "btn_pressed"
```

And you should run the gui in your main thread. Its not recommended to call gui calls from different threads.

Comment: But if I should not use different threads to call gui commands, how am I supposed to do this? The gui mainloop will block everything.

Comment: Write the timer part on a thread, but dont call gui functions directly from it. Instead, use a Queue, socket,variable, etc. Its just a recommendation.

Comment: I mean how am I supposed to write the new value to the variable is the `while True:` loop is not executed?

Comment: Hmmk, Idk how to use Queues... I am pretty bad with python... It is, lets say... not my mother-programming-language xD

Comment: I am gonna try that :)

Comment: I think in this case its fine to just run it.

Comment: Okay, works, I just assigned the variable in another thread where I placed that `while` loop and it updates automatic.
Thank You!

Comment: If it helped please select it as answer.